# What is the connection between the root test and the radius of convergence of the power series?

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$R=\dfrac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}} $$

I've been reading this paper regarding asymptotic growth, and I stumbled upon this relation between the radius of convergence and the root test. From my knowledge, the root test shows if the series converge of diverge with conditions
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=L
$$
If $L<1$, series converge, if $L>1$ series diverge, and if $L=1$ the series may be divergent, conditionally convergent, or absolutely convergent.

How have they connected the root test to the radius of convergence of the series?

Comment: What happens when you apply the root test to the series $\sum a_n x^n$  with a power of $x$ in there?

Comment: @GEdgar I am not sure...

Comment: @GEdgar Could you please elaborate on your comment a bit further? Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root test.
Consider a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.  Let
$$
L := \limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}
$$
Here $L \in [0,+\infty]$.  Then
$\bullet $ If $L<1$, the series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely [by comparison with a geometric series].
$\bullet $ If $L>1$, the series $\sum a_n$ diverges [since $a_n$ does not converge to $0$].
$\bullet $ If $L=1$, the test is inconclusive.

---

Now consider a power series $\sum c_n x^n$.  Let
$$
R:=\dfrac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}|c_n|^{1/n}} .
$$
Fix a value of $x$ with $0 < |x| < +\infty$.  Let $a_n = c_n x^n$.  Then
$$
L = \limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} |c_n x^n|^{1/n}
= \limsup_{n \to \infty} |c_n|^{1/n} |x| = \frac{|x|}{R} .  
$$
[we use the conventions $\frac{|x|}{0} = +\infty$ and $\frac{|x|}{+\infty} = 0$.]

So:
$\bullet $ If $|x|<R$, then $L<1$ so $\sum c_n x^n$ converges absolutely.
$\bullet $ If $|x|>R$, then $L>1$ so $\sum c_n x^n$ diverges.

These two hold for all $x$ with $0<|x|<+\infty$.  So the "radius of convergence" of the series $\sum c_n x^n$ is $R$.

Comment: Thank you so much!